# Using default sequence value in Postgresql table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm filling for someone at work today who is in charge of our SQL codebase. I don't have any experience with SQL.

I have a file called `exp_impl.sql` with this code:

```
create schema if not exists exp;
grant usage on schema exp to public;

create table exp.manifest 
(
  -- id INT PRIMARY KEY;
  -- some attributes are defined below and omitted
);
```

I received a request to add

```
default nextval('ids_id_seq')
```

after the primary key with the comment "I would like for the `id` here to share the same sequence as the `id` in the `result.ids` table".

I added this, and now the file looks like:

```
create schema if not exists exp;
grant usage on schema exp to public;

create table exp.manifest 
(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY default nextval('ids_id_seq');
  -- some attributes are defined below and omitted
);
```

Bazel tests we have for this file are running successfully, but from what I can see `ids_id_seq` isn't defined anywhere.

Do I need to create this sequence in the file? How can I expose this file to `result.ids` table -- is there some kind of header file I need to include?

Comment: 1) This `-- id INT PRIMARY KEY default nextval('ids_id_seq');` is not going to create anything as it is commented out 2) Is the DEFAULT for `result.ids` actually `nextval('ids_id_seq')`? 3) In `psql` does `\ds *.ids_id_seq` return anything?

Comment: I think you should read up on [basic DDL syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-table.html), [default values](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-default.html), [sequences](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) and [sequence manipulation functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html). Then you should be able to find your way.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver sorry, it is not commented out in my code. I accidentally commented it out here

Comment: @AdrianKlaver and yes, the `\ds *.ids_id_seq` does return a list of relations with 1 row showing that `ids_id_seq` is indeed a sequence.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe yes, I looked through some of the tutorial functions, but I am not sure if I need some kind of header here like in other languages. it seems the concept of header is not relevant to sql?

Comment: Right; there are no headers. The whole program is a single statement.

Comment: 1) What are the other relations named `*.ids_id_seq`? 2) Is the sequence in a schema(the * part) that can be found? In other words does in `psql` the command `show search_path` contain the schema that `ids_id_seq` is in?